# Execute file with certain PHP version

Tags: php, version

I need to execute a PHP file with another PHP version as installed. I know the full path to the other versions, but I do not know how to use it.

I have read the [PHP man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/php) but there is no mention of it. I assume I have to set the version first and then run it.

I know how to do it via `htaccess`, but isn't there a way to set the version directly in the command line?

Comment: See [this SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182176/does-php-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-virtualenv-or-rubys-sandbox).

Comment: Thanks! The last answer in your link is telling only a solution via scripts/PHP files. So did I understand it right, you can't just start your script with another PHP version on the fly (or almost on the fly) via console?

Comment: No idea; I understood the answers to suggest that it wasn't really possible, but I know SFA about PHP...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a php-script on the command-line, you should use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) pointing to the absolute path. A shebang is the first line in a script telling the shell which program to use to execute it:

```
#!/path/to/your/alternative/php
```

then make your script executable and just run it:

```
chmod +x yourscript.php
./yourscript.php
```

Or you just call it directly with the binary of your alternative php-version:

```
/path/to/your/alternative/php yourscript.php
```